# C# How to return the current folder in addition to the subfolders to process through each

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, as I use it infrequently via SSIS.

I have a job which I run daily, and I would like to find a way in C# to pass in a variable (Example RootPath) and for it to return the path folder, along with all sub folders.

I have been looking over Directory.GetDirectories, but it doesn't seem to include the RootPath as an array item.  Our files are written at the root level and then archived off to the folders as and when.

The Folder/File Structure is like this:

Folder (Root Lv 1)
- File 1
- File 2
Folder (Sub Lv 2)
 -- File 3
 -- File 4
Folder (Sub Lv 2)
 -- File 5
 -- File 6

Hope that makes sense?!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if this works for you: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: whatever you feed to Directory.GetDirectories as the input path _is_ the root directory of your structure, so if you gave a value to that, then you already know the root path. It's not clear what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` to get the current directory. However, if you want all the subdirectories, you'll need to use [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I believe `EnumerateDirectories` includes the root that you pass it, but don't quote me on that.